# devicetree and libgpiod with gpio-line-names - Issue

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, gpio, device-tree

I stay trying put name **LED** in my **GPIO6_IO14** of the imx7d-pico
(technexion) device/DEVICETREE (DTS/DTSi-files):
https://github.com/neuberfran/StackOverflow

I stay using Yocto/Zeus, kernel 5.6, **libgpiod** v1.4. I can blink
LED using GPIO6_IO14. But, when I try put label name (**LED**) in this GPIO
I get the issue shown on the screen below:

[image]

Can you help

Comment: Did you modify the arch/arm/boot/dts/imx7d-pico.dtsi file (the one with the syntax error)?

Comment: @Ian Abbott Yes i modified. As you can see in the README.md of the github link, I have modified the *.dtsi and *.dts (imx7d)

Comment: The comma-separated `gpio-line-names` properties should end with a semi-colon, not a comma. E.g. `gpio-line-names = "", "", ` ... `"LED", "",` ... `"", "";`.

Comment: @Ian Abbott tks. I have issue now in line 105

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KTb151kUzImUuh_QJhhl0xmafeETUHfq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- imx7d-pico-pi.dtb
  DTC     arch/arm/boot/dts/imx7d-pico-pi.dtb
Error: arch/arm/boot/dts/imx7d-pico.dtsi:105.19-20 syntax error
FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.lib:296: arch/arm/boot/dts/imx7d-pico-pi.dtb] Erro 1
make: *** [Makefile:1248: imx7d-pico-pi.dtb] Erro 2

Comment: The syntax error is on the `gpio-line-names =3D` lines. The `3D` part should not be there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234531/discussion-between-neuberfran-and-ian-abbott).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrongly relying on this link: http://next.patchew.org/Linux/20201201074125.11806-1-o.rempel@pengutronix.de/mbox
to resolve the issue. Using the implementation that revolved around the **3D** word that can be seen in such a link.

From the moment I based on the **3 links below**, I resolved the issue.

Just include in the **imx7d-pico.dtsi** file the items from **&gpio1 - &gpio7**. And in **&gpio6**, include "LED" in the fourteenth line.

https://sbexr.rabexc.org/latest/sources/1b/037aa2271810d7.html

https://sbexr.rabexc.org/latest/sources/12/6351a0f24647cd.html

https://sbexr.rabexc.org/latest/sources/d4/db1bab7dc0e22f.html